# What is the maximum capabilty of Magento 2 CE?

Tags: magento2, magento-community

I'm just curious about the capacity of my M2 website on the below;

- How many concurrent users do I have?
- How much load does it take?
- How many transactions can it handle?
  etc....

**My Server Specs**

SSD Web Space    -   160 GB

Data Transfer   -    5 TB

CPU Power       -    Quad-Core 2.5GHz

RAM Availability    - 8 GB ECC

I'm new to the website optimization area. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use of mysqltuner.pl will produce a Summary Report listing current activity rates and recommends configuration changes.  Being new to optimization, do not implement all their suggestions blindly.  Read the appropriate REFMAN details.  View my profile, Network Profile for contact info, including my Skype ID.  Would like to Skype Talk with you.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thanks for your reply. How do i use it?

Comment: Please post the complete report from mysqltuner.pl and I will provide some Suggestions to consider for your configuration to improve performance.